# Explicit expressions for the integrals of second degree polynomials in the orthogonal group

Tags: measure-theory, polynomials, orthogonal-matrices, random-matrices, haar-measure

Wikipedia has explicit formulas for first and second degree polynomial integrals in the unitary group using Weingarten functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weingarten_function).

Is there any closed form formula for similar integrals but in the Orthogonal group $O_d$? I am refering to integrals of the form:

$\int_{O_d} o_{ij} o_{kl} o_{mn} o_{pq} d\mu(O_d)$

where $\mu(O_d)$ is the Haar measure of the Orthogonal group.

I have found Theorem 2.1 and Proposition 2.2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.1258.pdf but I'm not sure how to go from this to a closed form formula, similar to the Wikipedia article. Thanks!